# Combining multiple .change functions into one using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few text input fields that will update some hidden fields.

I have a few `.change` functions that will watch for changes on the visible input fields.

Here is my JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tcgmr698/

### Jquery

```
    $("#TravellerContact_ManualAddress1").change(function () {
        $('input[id=TravellerContact_Address1]').val($('input[id=TravellerContact_ManualAddress1]').val())
    });

    $("#TravellerContact_ManualAddress2").change(function () {
        $('input[id=TravellerContact_Address2]').val($('input[id=TravellerContact_ManualAddress2]').val())
    });

    $("#TravellerContact_ManualAddress3").change(function () {
        $('input[id=TravellerContact_Address3]').val($('input[id=TravellerContact_ManualAddress3]').val())
    });

    $("#TravellerContact_ManualAddress4").change(function () {
        $('input[id=TravellerContact_Address4]').val($('input[id=TravellerContact_ManualAddress4]').val())
    });

    $("#TravellerContact_ManualAddress5").change(function () {
        $('input[id=TravellerContact_Address5]').val($('input[id=TravellerContact_ManualAddress5]').val())
    });

    $("#TravellerContact_ManualPostCode").change(function () {
        $('input[id=TravellerContact_PostCode]').val($('input[id=TravellerContact_ManualPostCode]').val())
    });
```

### HTML

```
<div id="manualFullAddress" class="fullAddress">
            <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress1" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress1" placeholder="Address" type="text">

            <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress2" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress2" placeholder="Address 2" type="text">
            <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress3" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress3" placeholder="Address 3" type="text">
            <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress4" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress4" placeholder="City" type="text">
            <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress5" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress5" placeholder="Province" type="text">
            <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualPostCode" name="TravellerContact_ManualPostCode" placeholder="Postal Code" type="text">
        </div>
```

### Hidden fields that get posted to the DB

```
<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address1" name="TravellerContact.Address1" type="hidden" value="">

<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address2" name="TravellerContact.Address2" type="hidden" value="">

<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address3" name="TravellerContact.Address3" type="hidden" value="">

<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address4" name="TravellerContact.Address4" type="hidden" value="">

<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address5" name="TravellerContact.Address5" type="hidden" value="">

<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_PostCode" name="TravellerContact.PostCode" type="hidden" value="">
```

My main question is how do I go about combining these functions into one function? Is it possible?

Comment: Use a `starts-with` selector for the id, add `this` and `String.prototype.replace()` and you're almost done.

Comment: Please consider changing your html, for example, for your manual field you could use `<input data-target="#TravellerContact_Address1" type="text" />`, than your JS would be much easier, starting with `$('[data-target]').on('change', function{ var thisInput = $(this); var thisTarget = $(thisInput.data('target')); thisTarget.val( thisInput.val() ); });` Just make your life easier... cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant elements are all children of `#manualFullAddress`. We can therefor add the `.change()` event handler to this parent element instead ("event delegation", but it would also work with one event handler per `<input />` element)

We can use `this` to get the id of the `<input />` element. And with `.replace("Manual", "")` we can get the id of the corresponding `<input type="hidden" />` element.

```js
$("#manualFullAddress").on("change", "input", function() {
  const input = $(this);

  $("#" + this.id.replace("Manual", "")).val(input.val());
});
```

```js
$("#manualFullAddress").on("change", "input", function() {
  const input = $(this);

  $("#" + this.id.replace("Manual", "")).val(input.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="manualFullAddress" class="fullAddress">
  <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress1" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress1" placeholder="Address" type="text">
  <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress2" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress2" placeholder="Address 2" type="text">
  <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress3" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress3" placeholder="Address 3" type="text">
  <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress4" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress4" placeholder="City" type="text">
  <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualAddress5" name="TravellerContact_ManualAddress5" placeholder="Province" type="text">
  <input class="form-control manualAddressEntry-js" id="TravellerContact_ManualPostCode" name="TravellerContact_ManualPostCode" placeholder="Postal Code" type="text">
</div>

<div>
"Hidden" Elements
<br />
<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address1" name="TravellerContact.Address1" value="">
<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address2" name="TravellerContact.Address2" value="">
<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address3" name="TravellerContact.Address3" value="">
<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address4" name="TravellerContact.Address4" value="">
<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_Address5" name="TravellerContact.Address5" value="">
<input class="HideValFromSet" id="TravellerContact_PostCode" name="TravellerContact.PostCode" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Great help @Andreas didn't know you could use the `.change` function on the parent div. The .replace was a great idea

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can bind change event using `.manualAddressEntry-js` and get the id dynamically as shown below.

```
$('.manualAddressEntry-js').change( function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("Manual", "");
  $(`input[id=${id}]`).val($(`input[id=${id}]`).val());
});
```

But I will recommend changing id to `data-` and using that instead of id, if you're not using it anywhere else.

Comment: You need to do replace also.